# Bundling Angular App with Gulp + Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular, gulp, lazy-loading, systemjs

I have been wrecking my head lately trying to figure this out.

I recently bundled an angular application using systemjs and gulp.

I had this all working and showed this to the client, they were still looking for performance gains and decided to implement lazy loading of some modules. We had not actually built the application with modules so we refactored to include modules for our features.

After getting the lazy loading to work in development environment, we decided to bundle the application again with systemjs and gulp.

However this time the application is unable to load the lazy loaded modules.

I was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem?

Comment: Likely to do with AOT compilation issues. This is something people learn to avoid, and is probably why Angular-CLI has become so popular. This doesn't solve your current problem, but I'd highly recommend looking into angular-cli's webpack bundler.

Comment: We had originally looked into webpack, but we noticed that when it was bundled, the templates were inlined into the bundle, so rather than use our templateUrl it was changing this to template. As we are using server side rendering this would not work. Unless there is a way to disable this in webpack?

Comment: Sounds like it's been a while since you last looked into Angular-CLI. It's come leaps and bounds (version 1.2.6 takes care of most of these types of issues), and has even made Angular - Universal (server side rendering of Angular apps) near obsolete (it provides most of the features by default).